# AP mode not showing in wifi interface mode in linux | for fake AP

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux, drivers, networkmanager

With `MT7601` chipset, I unable to see `AP` mode in the interface mode as below :

Info:

```
# iw list
Wiphy phy0
Supported interface modes:
     * managed
     * monitor
```

Driver:

```
# lsmod | grep 802
mac80211              782336  1 mt7601u
cfg80211              602112  2 mac80211,mt7601u
```

Hence, I unable to make access point in linux using `hostapd` :

```
kali@kali:~ $ sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf  -d

[10:06:06] Starting hostapd ...
Configuration file: hostapd.conf
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
```

TD;TR : Need a `AP` mode in `mt7601` chipset in kali linux to use AP (fake AP). Amazing matter is that `AP` work in Windows with same device.

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel is at least 4.2, right? If yes, then maybe you need to find a good copy of the mt7601u firmware. MediaTek's website is posting version 3.0.0.4 from 2013, which seems to be broken by some reports. See if you can find a different version somewhere.  Download it, and put it in /lib/firmware/

See if that works.

Comment: Thanks for hint version, just want to know that, does master mode enable with mt7601(monitor+AP) ? I'm using fluxion tool for captive portal for wifi cracks in Kali Linux.

Comment: When you luck into the correct driver/firmware combination, the AP mode should be listed too.